# How can I systematically add a time stamp to new documents in Meteor?

Tags: meteor

When a new document is inserted into a Collection, I'd like to add a time stamp to it. I want the server to do this, not the client. What is the best solution here?

Rem: I'd rather not implement my own custom `Meteor.methods()` for this, but use the classical `Meteor.Collection.insert()` method

Answer (score 7, accepted):

from here - https://github.com/oortcloud/unofficial-meteor-faq

> Blockquote
>
> How can I alter every document before it is added to the database?
>
> > There isn't support for this right now, but you can use a deny to achieve what you want on the server. For example, to timestamp each
> >     document as it goes into mongo:

```
Posts.deny({
  insert: function(userId, doc) {   
   doc.createdAt = new Date().valueOf();   
   return false; 
}})
```

```

Comment: Hi Nate! I had to put the space there between newDate() I hope that was ok

Answer (score 1):

Like Nate, to add a timestamp I used:

```
new Date().valueOf()
```

and attached it to a click event, like so:

```
"click #messageSubmit": function (evt, templ) {

  var message = templ.find('#messageText').value;

  Messages.insert({
    message: message,
    createdAt: new Date().valueOf()
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use `Date.now()`. It looks cleaner and returns the same value as `new Date().getTime()`.

```
new Date().getTime() === Date.now() // true
```